# PWM/PPM with external carrier

Tags: rf, pwm, amplitude-modulation

I want to generate PWM/PPM signal with external supplied carrier e.g. for 'outphasing' AM transmitter (for educational purposes). Convetional methods of PWM generation implies that carier signal has some fixed frequency. Typically PWM/PPM modulator has a ramp voltage generator that is designed for some known frequency. As far as I can understand, changing the input frequency will result in change of amplitude for that ramp voltage thus changing the modulation index. So, changing carrier frequency in wide range is impossible without some reconfiguration of modulator.

Is there any 'classic' circuit for doing this job? The best thoughts I have is to add some kind of 'AGC' for ramp voltage or for modulation signal. There also some crazy digital I/Q stuff, but maybe there is a simple way?

Comment: there are constant amplitude triangle generators. I use a [slow one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ex9gZ.jpg) all the time but there are [faster ones](https://m.eet.com/media/1051374/C0453pt2_4.pdf) too. what frequency do you need for this?

Comment: Thanks for you reply! 500-1700 KHz (MW broadcast band)

Comment: _" for 'outphasing' AM transmitter"_ - what exactly does this mean?

Comment: @BruceAbbott https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ampliphase

Answer (score 0):

Just to play around, drew up a potentially relevant triangle generator, that includes two of the subcircuits in the Dennis Feucht EE-times-article / book-excerpt linked in the comment above. I have not built this, don't know how far it can go with discrete components, and likely needs some changes. (I am happy to hear if there are fatal flaws and/or what needs to be fixed!).

[image]

One current into a resistor controls amplitude. Another current into a capacitor controls ramp rate. Frequency is controlled by ratio of the two currents. Voltage input controls level (should be buffered coming in). The delay introduced by the comparators and logic is expected to make amplitude control imperfect. Diodes something like BAS40 or BAS70?

Here is a [Falstad simulation](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjOCmC0CcIFYB0AmAzANlrLAOXsALAobBAvAiIWgFAAm1hu4hh1ADB6+yiPZABmAQwCuAGwAuDJizBtqOHiD4CRE6QHdZytnLB8UtbXAzgULU+AMgOxzt3ntCXcLD5h7pM08U-34F5KYAHeKijsdtoujqGuKBG2tJI6EdwxKi624NkcSGiwaCSwXGBoKAYcGOxgXMmpWWFp2RB5hGBgAOxohBgcBF2dsLjEtvmFxaXlldXgddGuIXx6bnxROksN3OsZKAhmu51rQWYoR34q+0nRzCrnh8c3LGfLSi-Xqfe3Fix2Ke1mNAcZy3IGRHLQFBITpcaryXAYNBoIYIlRIXDlBEcME4ArtGAdOY7UGYHSYOReMCA4EgcrcMGBABOtJQ9JpdNpGF+tKBXlBXJZ9IFdmE4FO5w6hnO8EISHgeQgtS4yrRXIiCAQuE6WqwR0SYCQGD6ypNpsVptoACUQNBfHszLaAvbcpxwIbjabPa1ckgEPYMPqAly5E7-fhViBg3djgBjSPh95RpFmdLQgncKFq4ia7WdXUJSJIUphljJ+OlgWebT7IUsFbkpIAc0QfU5LBrtJGuVoAEsbUpblZJT6uKzCL2dLcVsPtkXgRwjE9qJYB797FZB1T0hTrbbW5vQtz0twqNsxn6AB4geBItBzCBlmp8ADCAHkALIABQAgpbvwAVV9LQAZVoK9cH6WklFwK4ChlcwQAAIQAVQAMVQgBRS0S2jEBunFR5I0DV5-A8MC8I4eA9ngPM7xQANqDFEAADUAH1X2Q-9yMdKgfhtAxDDIRibAAGQw5iMJEgAdABnAAKRDX3-ABKPlS1ZMlSXWDsGyTYVyORG9hkQKpOAgJ8QGfZDLUtDCADl-1k4CAHUAEl-2fAAJLDuLAXA+E6KhbTKPC6wQ78vxE9zkIAEQwgzjLzagUBo+CbD-f94tFKlrA8GxhxlOUxnNU1aWhVV-OzLUdVgPUagtbQcr4vcVHDdYWuanKlHarqfDMbr1zeK4mquOxmSsZ0hwsFplUGnxppygw1zABA718JbMkcabDEQRBaBWtaFGdZpjpUbI-Ua-L8oUGd7GHd47XOdY7SyO1IOem7PpqJL1hOyCTtG+xmg24Gfrum6kr+tdGqO-7XrB5kOWOrJnQzWbtCR2CNIZHr+odRaU3XAnyyY9Yoxy8mAh6o6rgmwGAHtaU6Flsl6NB2zGE1aowfY9myPhkVpFj2M42h2ZUO9HCFtjFK48WgRdPIuDvVzWIiz8ov-WL4vl71Z1hEBVb-L9WIy+KgA) also for conceptual illustration (not a serious simulation). Has sliders on right hand side adjust the three inputs.

Also, following up a note in the same book excerpt, a more elaborate version of the current-switcher subcircuit is found in the left side of the "equivalent schematic" diagram of [this old NE566 datasheet](https://img.ozdisan.com/ETicaret_Dosya/485105_9303808.PDF)

Comment: Interresting, thank you!